# Find column values where first letter is upper case

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table EMP_INFO with EID, ENAME, GENDER. My objective is to display only those ENAME values where the first letter is Capital or uppercase.

Table like:

```
EID     ENAME     GENDER
001     Samuel    M
002     john      M
003     susan     F
004     CALEB     M
```

Desired output like:

```
EID    ENAME
001    Samuel
004    CALEB
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT EID, ENAME
FROM EMP_INFO
WHERE ENAME like '[A-Z]%';
```

But this is just giving a blank output. No errors, no warnings but no output as well. Also I am using oracle sql developer.

Comment: What if `ENAME` is equal to `CAleb`, for example? Is that good or bad?

Comment: Any Ename which starts with Uppercase letter can be counted. For eg. In this case CAleb would work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like the following (assuming you've not [done anything to make your SQL queries case-insensitive](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/2005_5_20_great_technique_case_sensitive_text_searching.htm)):

```
SELECT eid, ename
  FROM emp_info
 WHERE ename >= 'A'
   AND ename < CHR(ASCII('Z')+1);
```

This will ensure that the first character of `ename` falls between `A` and `Z` inclusive. The value of `CHR(ASCII('Z')+1)` is `[` but that's not terribly important - I think it's clearer to use the functions in this case than the "magic character".

**EDIT:** The reason this works is that lower-case characters, as a group, appear after upper-case characters in many character sets*, so as long as a value of `ename` is between `A` and `Z` inclusive, according to the typical string comparison, it will start with an upper-case character.

*For example, [here is the Unicode character table](https://unicode-table.com/en/) and [here is the ASCII character table](https://www.asciitable.com/). I suspect that this solution may not work with EBCDIC character sets but I don't have a server handy on which I can confirm that suspicion.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the solution. This query is running just fine . Could you please explain the Where part of this query ? Thankyou

Comment: Hi @AkanshaKaushik, sure. Lower-case characters, as a group, appear after upper-case characters in typical character sets, so as long as a value of `ename` is between `A` and `Z` inclusive, according to the typical string comparison, it will start with an upper-case character.

Comment: Okay Got it David. Thank you so much again. Appreciate this explanation . :)

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does not support wildcards in the `LIKE` pattern.  You can use regular expressions instead:

```
select EID , ENAME
from EMP_INFO
where regexp_like(ENAME, '^[A-Z]');
```

Alternatively, you could just compare the first character:

```
where substr(ENAME, 1, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'Z'
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/QAGG59701) is a working example of this version.

By default, Oracle is case-sensitive, so these should work on most Oracle systems.

Comment: Thank you Gordon for the editing part as well as for the answer. I tried the first one, it is working fine. It is giving me the desired output. I also tried the second one , shows error - 'ORA-00920: invalid relational operator'

Comment: @Kaushik . . . Nothing looks wrong to me and it works when I test it.

Comment: Is this a typo? Wildcard character in LIKE are "%" and "_" At least one can misunderstood your statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Your first query , I thought was working fine. But it gives incorrect answers if I Change format of my ename a bit. What I meant is I only want those Ename's whose 1st letter is uppercase, the REGEX_LIKE query is returning any ename with uppercase letter at any position. Eg. I used meGHan , it is also returning that as a output.

Comment: @Kaushik . . . If it is doing that, then you are missing the `^` at the beginning of the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

We have a well-known function called `initcap` to be considerable :

```
SELECT EID, ENAME
  FROM EMP_INFO
 WHERE substr(ENAME,1,1) = substr(initcap(ENAME),1,1);
```

or alternatively use :

```
SELECT EID, ENAME
  FROM EMP_INFO
 WHERE ENAME between chr(65) and chr(92);
```

[***SQL Fiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9f4586/6)

Comment: You could just do `ename IN (INITCAP(ename), UPPER(ename))`

Comment: @DavidFaber Hello David, Thank you for the answer. It is working and giving expected & desired outputs. Cheers!

Comment: @Kaushik . . . But I don't understand why you accepted this.  It will reject `'McDonald'` for instance.

Comment: True, it did reject an Ename value that I later added ToNy .

Comment: @Kaushik  have you looked at the SQL Fiddle Demo ( the last arrangement works for `McDonald` or `ToNy` ) ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Sorry Sir with the delay in reply. I just checked the SQL Fiddle Demo. Its working amazingly. Giving the desired output. I just wanted to confirm one thing though, this query is comparing between the 1st character of the value field, and 1st character of the INITCAP function output, right ?

Comment: @Kaushik exactly dear friend.

Comment: Thank you Barbaros & Gordon, this helped a lot. Appreciate it !